# why uploaded zip file via ftp is smaller then original file?

Tags: java, ftp, zip, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

My original zip file is 4KB. When i upload it via ftp on server, the size is smaller namely 3.032KB.it seems to me zip file is corrupted and can't be open. Why it happens? how can be fixed?

**ftp code**

```
public static void uploadFilesToServer(String filename){

    File file = new File(filename);
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        client.connect("ftpsrv2.koln.de");
        client.login("user", "pass");
        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        if(client.storeFile(file.getName(), fis)){
            System.out.println("Upload success");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Upload faild");
        }
        client.logout();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it 4 k due to the cluster size on your hard-drive? Have you really checked the exact byte size?

Comment: Define "fixed"--have you verified the file is no longer valid? Or are  you just assuming however you're looking at the file size is reporting its actual size in bytes?

Comment: If i put bigger zip file result is the same. uploaded file is smaller and can't be open. seems to be corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is fine, 4kb is the minimum block size of your disk. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420757/whats-the-actual-file-size).

Comment: Everything is not fine because zip file is corrupted and can't be open.

Comment: As your code seems fine, have you tried uploading a file with an non java based ftp client? Maybe it's a server fault.

Comment: yes i did with FileZilla and everything is OK. i'm using Win7 64bit, can it cause the problem?

Comment: Don't think so. Have you tried using the overload of the method, where you can pass the bytesize as the second parameter?

Comment: which method overload ?